# ODI 12C CDC Objects

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I would like to know if it possible define the names of

> J$tables & views

.

Currently in my source database, we have 2 tables with same name in different schema
`(complaints.action_item  & change.action_item)`.

The CDC objects like J$ views, tables and triggers are maintained in a common work schema `(CDC_WORK)`.
So I'm not able to create 
`J$tables and T$ triggers` for CDC using ODI as there is name conflict.

Is it possible to specify the CDC object names somewhere in ODI so that I could enable CDC on both tables.